# Spresense SORACOM HARVEST-FILES データアップロード方法

Tags: spresense, arduino, soracom

Aruduino IDEでプログラミングし、SORACOM HARVEST-FILESにデータをアップロードしたく考えておりますが
SORACOM側で"Harvest Files destination returms 404 Not Found"で/logs/にアップロード出来ない状況となっています。現状のソースは以下となります。
何か不足している情報等がありましたらご教授お願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ソースコードは画面キャプチャ (画像) ではなく、文字のまま質問に貼り付けてください。

Comment: サーバ側に logs ディレクトリは存在するのでしょうか？場合によっては予め作成しておく必要があるかもしれません。